# Merge sort algorithm not working

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

Here is my code for a mergesort in java:

```
public class MergeSort {

    public static void mergesort(int[] input) {

        int inputSize = input.length;
        if(inputSize < 2) {
            return;
        }
        int[] left = new int[inputSize/2];
        int[] right = new int[inputSize/2];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < inputSize/2; i++) {
            left[i] = input[i];
        }
        for(int i=inputSize/2; i<inputSize; i++) {
            right[count] = input[i];
            count++;
        }

        mergesort(left);
        mergesort(right);
        merge(left, right, input);

    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] returnArr, int[] left, int[] right) {
        int leftSize = left.length;
        int rightSize = right.length;
        int i = 0;
        int j =0;
        int k = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
            if(left[i] <= right[j]) {
                returnArr[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                returnArr[k] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while(i<leftSize) {
            returnArr[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j < rightSize) {
            returnArr[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        for(int x=0; x<returnArr.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(returnArr[x]);
        }

        return returnArr;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {3,4,6,2,7,1,8,6};
        mergesort(array);

    }

}
```

My issue is that I'm getting an out of bounds exception. 
I'm using the debugger and have found that after mergesort(left) and mergesort(right) have finished recursively running.

The arrays left and right, which go into the merge function, have the values [3] and [4] respectively, which is correct.

But when the debugger jumps into the merge function, left has value [3] and right, for some reason is length 2 and has the value [3,4].

This is the source of my out of bounds exception, though I'm not sure why when the merge function runs for its first time, it changes the value of "right".

Comment: Add the stacktrace

Comment: Use a debugger and you will find out what is happening

Comment: Is it possible you have a typo there: Shouldn't `merge(left, right, input);` be `merge(input, left, right);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem that is readily visible is that the you shouldn't make 2 arrays of size `inputSize/2`. Make two arrays of `inputSize/2` and `inputsize-inputSize/2`. Otherwise the algorithm would fail for odd length array.

Also call the function with proper order of the arguments. `merge( input, left, right);`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code and merged them to 1 method, `left.length` and `right.length` are limited by `input.length` so you only need to loop by `input.length`:

```
public static void mergeSort(int[] input)
{
    if (input.length < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    int[] left = new int[input.length / 2];
    int[] right = new int[input.length - input.length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        if (i < input.length / 2)
            left[i] = input[i];
        else
            right[i - input.length / 2] = input[i];
    }

    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);

    for (int i = 0, l = 0, r = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        if (l >= left.length)
        {
            input[i] = right[r];
            r++;
        }
        else if (r >= right.length)
        {
            input[i] = left[l];
            l++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (left[l] >= right[r])
            {
                input[i] = right[r];
                r++;
            }
            else
            {
                input[i] = left[l];
                l++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you had two problems with your code:

1- as @coderredoc said: your left and right array sizes are wrong:

exemple: if you had an array of 7 elements, your left and right arrays would have a size of 7/2 = 3 so you would have a total of 6 elements in left and right arrays and not 7.

2- you are calling merge function in the mergeSort function with wrong parameters order:
it should be returnArr, left, right and not left,right, returnArr.

Explanation:

if you pass the left array as the first parameter, it would merge the right and the returnArr in the left array. But your left array has a size of 3 and the sum of the sizes of the others is 7 + 3 = 10 that's why you got an OutOfBoundsException.

you need to call merge(input,left,right);

here is the final version:

```
public class MergeSort {

    public static void mergesort(int[] input) {

        int inputSize = input.length;
        if(inputSize < 2) {
            return;
        }
        int[] left = new int[inputSize/2];
        int[] right = new int[inputSize-inputSize/2];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < inputSize/2; i++) {
            left[i] = input[i];
        }
        for(int i=inputSize/2; i<inputSize; i++) {
            right[count] = input[i];
            count++;
        }

        mergesort(left);
        mergesort(right);
        merge(input,left, right);

    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] returnArr, int[] left, int[] right) {
        int leftSize = left.length;
        int rightSize = right.length;
        int i = 0;
        int j =0;
        int k = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while(i < leftSize && j < rightSize) {
            if(left[i] <= right[j]) {
                returnArr[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                returnArr[k] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while(i<leftSize) {
            returnArr[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j < rightSize) {
            returnArr[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        for(int x=0; x<returnArr.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(returnArr[x]);
        }

        return returnArr;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {3,4,6,2,7,1,8,6};
        mergesort(array);

    }

}
```

Comment: Yep, this was it. Just a simple mistake. Thanks!